# Counting occurrences of string for each unique row across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count the occurrence of certain strings in multiple columns and return the total counts in a new column

So I know I can use value_counts to count the total occurrence of values in a given column:

```
data['col'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Result:

```
[["win" TKO technical knockout]     336
[["win" UD unanimous decision]      307
[["win" KO knockout]                225
[["loss" UD unanimous decision]      97
[["loss" TKO technical knockout]     64
[["win" nan null]                    53
[["draw" MD majority decision]       43
[["loss" KO knockout]                41
[["loss" MD majority decision]       35
[["loss" nan null]                   32
[["loss" SD split decision]          29
[["unknown" nan null]                29
[["win" SD split decision]           27
[["draw" PTS null]                   18
[["win" RTD corner retirement]       17
[["draw" SD split decision]          12
[["loss" RTD corner retirement]      11
[["win" MD majority decision]         9
[["loss" DQ disqualification]         6
[["win" PTS null]                     6
[["unknown" NC null]                  3
```

Problem is I want to for example count the occurrences of [["win" KO knockout] in every relevant column (relevant columns are col1 to col20).

Here is a sample of my data:

```
{'col1': {0: ['["win" UD unanimous decision'],
  1: ['["win" UD unanimous decision'],
  2: ['["win" TKO technical knockout'],
  3: ['["win" UD unanimous decision'],
  4: ['["win" UD unanimous decision']},
 'col2': {0: ['["win" TKO technical knockout'],
  1: ['["win" TKO technical knockout'],
  2: ['["win" TKO technical knockout'],
  3: ['["win" UD unanimous decision'],
  4: ['["win" UD unanimous decision']},
 'col3': {0: ['["win" TKO technical knockout'],
  1: ['["win" KO knockout'],
  2: ['["win" TKO technical knockout'],
  3: ['["win" TKO technical knockout'],
  4: ['["win" UD unanimous decision']},
 'col4': {0: ['["win" UD unanimous decision'],
  1: ['["win" UD unanimous decision'],
  2: ['["win" KO knockout'],
  3: ['["win" TKO technical knockout'],
  4: ['["win" UD unanimous decision']}}
```

The desired output in this case would be:

```
      win UD   win TKO   win KO 
0       2         2         0
1       2         1         1
2       0         3         1
3       2         2         0
4       4         0         0
```

Update:

I have also tried using size and groupby:

```
#list of column names
col_outcome = ['col'+str(i) for i in range(1,11)]
data.groupby(col_outcome).size()
```

However this returns this error message:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Can you give a sample piece of data and code, so that we can run it by copy/paste?

Comment: @PrinceFrancis I added a sample of my data as dictionary in my question - only limited it to 4 columns

Comment: You asked for count the occurrences of [["win" KO knockout]. But your expected result is something other. I am confused, that is why I asked a simple example

Comment: `df.stack().value_counts()`?  or `df.melt(value_name='vals')['vals'].value_counts()`

Comment: @PrinceFrancis That was just an example to make the question clearer, will remove it if its causing confusion

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks, but problem is I would like to return the total count for each user as opposed the total number each string appears for all users- if that makes sense?

Comment: @Emm I don't see users in your input data.

Comment: @ScottBoston sorry, by users i mean for each row in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, let's reshape the "wide" dataframe to "long" with `stack` then do a little data string clean-up then `extract` and `replace` using regex, next `groupby` and `apply` `value_count`, lastly use `unstack` to reshape results:

```
df.stack().str[0].str.replace('\[|\"','')\
  .str.extract('(\w+\s\w+)')\
  .groupby(level=0)[0].apply(pd.Series.value_counts).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   win KO  win TKO  win UD
0       0        2       2
1       1        1       2
2       1        3       0
3       0        2       2
4       0        0       4
```